# Posts from a category on homepage with category archieves page default css

Tags: categories, query-posts, homepage

I am trying to accomplish something.

First am using two themes on my blog, on the mobile theme which is carrington, i would love to add five posts from a certain category or tag for example "Tech" to the footer of the theme or immediately after the recent posts.

Update: what i think am trying to achieve is:

category archieve pages and tag archieves has the same design (css) as the homepage.

i just need to copy the design and contents of one category page archieve and place it in the footer section of my homepage.

Any help please[image: The first section shows recent post then the other section (IN THE NEWS) shows post from a particular category with the design and css of the original post page. That is what am trying to achieve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my mission was achieved by using some part of the code suggested above.

I changed the xxxxx to my category slug then below that code i posted all of my loop and that was it.

So if you want it to have your post page design:

1. copy this
2. copy the whole of your loop and paste under and save

Answer (score 1):

```
    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => 5,
        'cat' => 77 // 77 - id category
    );

    $query = new WP_Query( $args );

    // loop
    if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
            $query->the_post();
echo '<li>';
the_post_thumbnail();
            echo '<a href="'.get_permalink().'">' . get_the_title() . '</a></li>';
        }
    } else {
        // posts not fount
    echo 'posts not fount';
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
```

Replace the category id (77) with the id of the category you need. You need to add this code to the template. In the place where you want to display the records (for example: index.php).

Comment: thanks. i added the code to my index.php and it went down to bottom of the page and it does not show thumbnails. it shows like a related post. i want it to have my template css with thumbnails and also show immediately under my original post. thanks. any more help

Comment: Updated code, displayed a thumbnail

Comment: hi i edited my post, check if you can understand what am really trying to achieve

Comment: how do i style it to look like my post page. i.e my default post page style

Comment: Can you link to the site?

Comment: i have managed to achieve my aim but something is not right. The number of post is not restricted to 5. it shows all the posts from that category

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php query_posts('category_name=xxxxxxxxxxxx&order=dsc&showposts=12'); ?>
        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
<br clear="all"><br />
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

Here you see category_name=xxxxxxxxxxxx   here change the xxxx to your category slug and you are done

Comment: Hi thanks, yours also shows the title of the post with underlines. but what i need is the posts to look like my original posts with thumbnails. just immediately below the recent posts

Comment: Please do not use `query_posts()` - [it breaks things](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts).

Comment: hi i edited my post, check if you can understand what am really trying to achieve